# Adding Support Request Contributor role to subscription

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-rbac

I am setting up an Azure subscription such that users have the ability to open support requests. When I try to add a role I see that all of the options are disabled. Can someone either help me understand what permissions need to be enabled or where the proper documentation on this is?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a prerequisite to be able to assign Azure roles, you must have `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permissions, such as [User Access Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) or [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner). If you don't have permissions to assign roles, the `Add role assignment` option will be disabled.

Check [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) for more details.